# Конвертация H/s в Mh/S

Tags: python, криптография

Я пишу бота для получения статистики с майнинг фермы. Но тут одна задача, моя программа для майнинга в API выдает ответ в *H/s*, а мне нужно сконвертировать *H/s* в *Mh/s*. Пример:
"pool_speed: 27517142", а исходный результат должен быть в виде "pool_speed: 27.51 Mh/s". Как можно реализовать конвертацию в Python?

Comment: Разделить и округлить?

Comment: Можно сделать и так, не сильно важно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, в каком виде получаются данные, но можно использовать f-строки, например:

```py
x = 27517142
print(f'{x/1_000_000:.2f}')
# 27.52
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо огромное!